# trouble installing grails csv plugin

Tags: grails, dependencies, grails-plugin

Im trying to install the grails csv plugin, i typed "grails install-plugin csv" and when I tried to install it, it gave me an error saying "UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES", "net.sf.opencsv#opencsv;2.3: not found" and below that it says that the Plugin has missing jar dependencies. I was able to install the spring-security-core plugin without any issues why is this not working?

Comment: Which version of grails are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I went in my buildConfig and in that file i uncommented the following lines of code:

```
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
mavenRepo "http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org"
mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
```

once I did that and ran grails install-plugin again the plugin was installed successfully